# Solve $3 \ln(x)-x=0$

Tags: calculus, real-analysis, logarithms

> Find the exact number of solutions in $(0,\infty)$ of the equation
>   $$3\ln(x)-x=0$$

There are two solutions, but I don't know how to reach them.

By using Mathematica we can see the plot

`Plot[3 Log[x] - x, {x, 0, 5}]`

[image]

Comment: use the Newton Raphson method

Comment: You are not asked to find the solutions, just their number. You should isolate the monotonies...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since you are only interested in the *number* of solutions, you can study the function

$$f(x)=3\ln(x)-x.$$

You have $f'(x)=\frac 3x-1$ so

$$f'(x)\geq 0\iff x\leq 3.$$

You now just have to remark that $f(3)>0$, which gives you exactly two solutions (using the intermediate value theorem) on $(0,+\infty)$ since this function is continuous.

Answer (score 0):

Consider $f(x)=3\ln(x)-x$ so that $\displaystyle f'(x)=\frac3x-1$.

We have $f'(x)=0$ only at $x=3$.

$f'(x)>0$ for $x \in (0,3)$ and $f'(x) < 0$ for $x \in (3, \infty)$.

Therefore, there is only $1$ sign change in the derivative which means a maximum of $2$ solutions.

This can be verified by noting $f(1)<0$, $f(3)>0$, and $f(5)<0$, and then applying the Intermediate Value Theorem on the intervals $(1,3)$ and $(3,5)$, because $f(x)$ is continuous on $(0,\infty)$.